# Difference between Approximate and Proximate?

Tags: differences

So I searched and a few questions that mention variations of this word but none that asked what the difference was?

I have heard:

*Approximate* & *Proximate*

*Approximately* & *Proximity*

But never:

**Approximity** or **Proximately**

> I live within close *proximity* to the bus stop.

OR

> It was *approximately* 5m.

How does the prefix "ap" change the word?

---

NOTE (for the fans): The words I typed as "never heard" coincidentally came up with red lines for spell check...

Comment: There's also the word proximal, which might be used instead of "proximately"

Comment: And of course the noun form of _approximate_ is _approximation_. But that's the act or result of approximating.

Comment: But none of this tells us why we don't use _approximity_.  What would that mean? Well, if proximity is the _state_ of being near, approximity would be the _state_ (not act or result) of going nearer?  But an action is not a state.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock Shouldn't you be saying why in your answer? After all, I did ask it. Do I really have to explain why we don't to get an answer?

Comment: Other people answered. I only made Comments, as I do not feel I have an answer, just some thoughts. No, you don't have to explain anything to me.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock I'm sorry. I sounded very rude! Nothing like an apology 4.5 years later... But anyway, I completely agree with you, hence my question. :) I don't know why I responded that way. I think I wanted you to answer so I could mark this as "Answered".

Answer (score 7):

Both proximate and approximate come from the latin proximāre, which means close or near. Both proximate and approximate indicate being near or close to something, but approximate is usually used to indicate being within a certain range of a goal, while proximate usually means physically close. When talking about measurements, you'd say that a sharp stick is approximately three inches long, meaning its length is near to, but not exactly, three inches.

If you said the stick was proximate to my eye, that would mean the stick is physically close to my eye.

Both are usually adjectives, but can also be verbs. However approximate as a verb is much more common than proximate.

The prefix ap comes from the latin ad, meaning to, so approximate could be said to mean *to come close to*

http://www.oed.com/search?searchType=dictionary&q=proximate

Answer (score 3):

Both words can mean close by in position, quality, and accuracy.

The *OED*'s examples for "proximate" illustrate its sense of closeness in the meaning of words, geographical position, and strength of commercial relationships.  The substitution of "approximate" would be apt in these examples, given its definition "Very near, in position or in character."

From *[History of the Berwickshire Naturalists' Club, Volume 1](https://books.google.com/books?id=sAlBAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA198&lpg=PA198&dq=toward%20the%20base%20of%20the%20arm%20they%20became%20approximate&source=bl&ots=4kWH2Fni-x&sig=A3CUGkbniGJGZa3hZth7ZwAvw2s&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAGoVChMImKjIu9rUxwIVhnY-Ch0Adw7j#v=onepage&q=approximate&f=false)* (which is quoted in part as an example from the *OED*) describing the suckers of an octopus:

> [T]oward the base of the arm they are larger and not in contact, but
>   they soon become **approximate**, and gradually lessening in size they
>   become very minute at the tips....

"Proximate," however has a usage that its cousin lacks -- next or previous in order.  This may be temporal (as in the "**proximate** future," something that will happen next as opposed to remote events to come), or causal

> The jury had to determine the **proximate** cause of the collision

or with respect to process, particularly in chemistry, in which "**proximate** analysis" of a compound means determining the compound's precursors.

Both words have synonymous adverbial forms -- "proximately" and "approximately."

Both words have synonymous noun forms, but with different morphemes -- "proximity," "proximateness" and "approximation."

Only "approximate" is a verb.